# Angular DatePicker hours?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to display angular datepicker, just to show hours, not minutes or date?

I know i can call it like this

```
<div class="ng-isolate-scope" view="hours" date-picker="start"></div>
```

But i dont need to select minutes?

Comment: would [this](https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker) work? Choose a step of 60 and you will only be able to select hours

Comment: But only to be inline

Answer (score 0):

Use time picker instead?
 Anyway you could also edit your value something like this '{{start|date:'HH'}}'